# Does charge of capacitor at constant voltage change after dielectric material is inserted?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, capacitance

I have a planar geometry capacitor, connected to a battery that supplies V volts. Initially there is vacuum/air in between both plates.
Afterwards, some dielectric material is inserted in between both plates, filling the capcitor as follows, with the green thing being the dielectric :

[image: Capacitor]

I am asked to compare the initial and final electric fields. The plates are never disconnected from the battery.

My question is the following: Should the charge of each plate be the same in the initial and final states?

My thoughts on it: Since the plates are never disconnected, the voltage will remain constant, and so Qf/Cf=Qo/Co. Since i put some dielectric, as far as i understand, Cf should be higher than Co, and so Qo should be proportionally higher than Qf. Also, based on Spirko's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220736/filling-a-charged-capacitor-with-dielectric-material), the battery will change the charge in the plates to mantain the voltage.

Is this correct?

Comment: It's definitely a much better post now. Deleting old comments... Looks like you already answered your own question too :)

Comment: You are asked about the electric field where?

Comment: There's only gonna be between the plates, so there i suppose.

Comment: See below, there are two values for the electric field, one in the dielectric, one in the vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. The potential difference between the plates remains the same, so the charge is increased by the same factor as the capacitance is increased - let's call this factor $k$ and let the dielectric have *relative* permittivity $\epsilon$ and fill a fraction $f$ of the plate separation $d$.

So $V = Q_0 d/\epsilon_0 A$, where $A$ is the plate area and the electric field initially between the plates $E_0 = Q_0/\epsilon_0 A$, which you can confirm with Gauss's law.

Then insert the dielectric. $V$ stays the same, but the E-field now has two values, one in the vacuum $E_v$ and a lower value inside the dielectric $E_d$. The displacement field is the same throughout the space between the plates and is given by Gauss's law as $D=Q_f/A$.

From the relation between E-field and potential 
$$V = (1-f)d E_v + fdE_d$$
 and 
$$E_v =\epsilon E_d = D/\epsilon_0 = Q_f/\epsilon_0 A.$$

Putting this all together:
$$ E_0 d = (1-f)d \epsilon E_d +fd E_d$$
$$ E_d = \frac{E_0}{(1-f)\epsilon +f}$$

All other quantities of interest follow from this...

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the capacitor (when the dielectric is inserted) as being 2 separate capacitors in series: one of width $d$ and the other of width $(L-d)$, where $d$ is the width of the dielectric material and $L$ is the separation of the two metal plates.

If you have two capacitors, 1 and 2 in series, the effective capacitance is

$$C_{eff}=\frac{C_1C_2}{C_1+C_2}$$

where $C_i=\frac{\epsilon_i A}{d_i}$, $\epsilon_i$ is the permittivity of the material between the capacitor plates, $A$ is the area of the plates and $d_i$ is the separation of the plates.

You can then use this expression and the formula $Q_{new}=C_{eff}V$ to find out what the new charge on the plates will be when you have a dielectric inside. You are right that $V$ will not change, as long as you are not running out of battery.